# Syntax highlighting for emails

Tags: email, html, syntax-highlighting, code

I'm once in a while sending raw code to customers. Is there a tool which adds (inline) styles to code, so that it is easier to read for my customers? A tool which works for gmail and other web-based (html) email clients would be great, but I would be also ok with a thunderbird extension.

Answer (score 2):

Although I'm still open to better suggestions, I've found some solutions myself.

- the thunderbird extension [pasteCode](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/thunderbird/addon/pastecode/)
- If you're using vim, you can use `:TOhtml`, which will generate a coloured html-version of your code

Comment: I have gone the ViM route before, but I have come to the conclusion that anyone that cares about syntax highlighting has access to an editor that highlights it the way that they like and they will just drop the code in there if they want highlighting that bad anyway. So I don't bother highlighting for them anymore.

Comment: If you haven't found a solution seven years later, then why not accept your own answer? Doing so will help other who read this question in future.

Answer (score 2):

I just came across this extension for chrome, firefox, and thunderbird, **Markdown here**:

http://markdown-here.com/

It gives markdown and latex support to writing emails in thunderbird or gmail in your browser.  It also has support for syntax highlighting in a variety of languages.  I tried it out with sending some Matlab code, and it worked really well!

I also tried **pasteCode**, but its not supported in the latest versions of thunderbird anymore.